# Make view width wrap_content, but no more than 0.5 weight

Tags: android, layout

In my LinearLayout I have two child ViewGroups, basically I want them to take 50% of space each (and it is done), but there is also a possibility that content of one of these ViewGroups is much smaller than 50%, in this case, is there any way to make second view match the remaining space?

Now my layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

<include layout="@layout/layout1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<include layout="@layout/layout2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And what I want to achieve is: one layout wrap_content, but no more than 50%, and the second layout fill remaining space.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make two layouts inside of your linear layouts,and give each of these a `layout_weight` of `0.5`. Then in each of these put a your view groups with the trait `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. As such -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_weight="0.5"
       ......
<include layout="@layout/layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_weight="0.5"
     ......
<include layout="@layout/layout2"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: You're the man! It worked. I made outer LinearLayouts weight 0.5 and with to wrap_content. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jcw, what parameters are you using for the `......` you ommitted? Should the middle linear layout be wrap_content, match_parent, or what?